# I would like to Trim Spaces which is in a single string

Tags: java

```
                       :     VJ NT jdbc & hyC rayan asdALAYA
                                                                8 CHURCH ROAD 9 TH FLOOR
                                                PUNE 3256-34546561
                                                PUNE 412346
```

this is in  a  single string which has lots of spaces I would like trim all extra spaces and give a single space for each word.Please help me

Comment: What actual output do you want?

Comment: do you want to simply `replace` multiple spaces with `one space`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try replacing all blocks of multiple spaces with a single space:

```
String input = "    :     VJ NT jdbc & hyC rayan asdALAYA";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

If you also want to remove a leading or trailing space which might be leftover, you can use [String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) for that:

```
input = input.trim();
```